# URL slashes are removed

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I have a .NET application that writes an HTML page. One page loads a lot of iframes, so I need to have them run onclick (rather than at page load).

```
b.Body = "<iframe id=" & Chr(34) & linkID & Chr(34) & "></iframe><a href=" & Chr(34) & "javascript:document.getElementById('" & linkID & "').src=" & Chr(34) & link & Chr(34) & ";></a>"
```

The problem is once it writes, it removes all slashes from my URL. I've tried escaping them, but spaces are included (which breaks the URL). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use single quotes inside the string for attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use double double quotes as a replacement of single double quotes and use single quotes to write string inside javascript

```
b.Body = "<iframe id=""" & linkID & """></iframe><a href=""" & "javascript:document.getElementById('" & linkID & "').src='" & link & "';""></a>"
```

Comment: `<iframe id="j94nw934tpxj"></iframe><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('j94nw934tpxj').src=""http://myurl.com/path"";></a>`

Didn't work.

Comment: no you are wrong. paste it `.src='" & link & "';""` exactly

Comment: after src & before semicolon it should be single quotes